# Working with Linked List Stacks

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

```
public class Matcher {

public MatchRtnCode matcher(String str){

    Stack<Character> s=new LLStack<Character>();
    for(int i =0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char c=str.charAt(i);
        if(c=='{' || c=='[' || c=='('){
            s.push(c);
        }else if (c=='}'){
            Character temp=s.pop();
            if(temp!='{'){
                s.push(temp);
                return MatchRtnCode.UNEXPECTED_SYMBOL;
            }


        }else if (c==']'){
            Character temp=s.pop();
            if(temp!='['){
                s.push(temp);
                return MatchRtnCode.UNEXPECTED_SYMBOL;
            }

        }else if (c==')'){
            Character temp=s.pop();
            if(temp!='('){
                s.push(temp);
                return MatchRtnCode.UNEXPECTED_SYMBOL;
            }

        }else{

        }
    }
    Character temp = s.pop();
    if(temp=='{' || temp=='[' || temp=='('){
        return MatchRtnCode.TOO_MANY_OPEN_SYMBOLS;
    }else if(temp=='}' || temp==']' || temp==')'){
        return MatchRtnCode.TOO_MANY_CLOSED_SYMBOLS;
    }else {
        return MatchRtnCode.GOOD_STRING;
    }

}
}
```

The Stack class is:

```
 import java.util.EmptyStackException;

 public interface Stack<E> {

public void push(E data) throws StackFullException;
public E pop() throws EmptyStackException;
public boolean isEmpty() throws EmptyStackException;
```

}

And the LLStack class is:

```
 import java.util.EmptyStackException;


public class LLStack<E> implements Stack<E> {
public Node top;
private class Node{
    public E data;
    public Node next;
    public Node(E data, Node next){
        this.data=data;
        this.next=next;
    }
}

public LLStack() {
    top = null;
}

@Override
public void push(E data) throws StackFullException {

    top=new Node(data, top);
}

@Override
public E pop() throws EmptyStackException {
    if(top==null){
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    E data=top.data;
    top=top.next;
    return data;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return top==null;
}
}
```

I am checking a string example: {[(ab)]} to make sure that there are the same number of {[( as there are }]).  Right now it is just printing out EmptyStackError.  How do I fix this?

Comment: for me it prints UNEXPECTED_SYMBOL

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(s.pop()=='{'){
     s.pop();
 }
```

pop() changes the state of the stack. You either need to peek or remember to push back on once you pop() and don't need it.

so try:

```
 char temp = s.pop();
 if(temp != '{') {
     s.push(temp);
 }
```

Or just make a peek method:

```
public char peek() {
    char c = s.pop();
    s.push(c);
    return c;
}
```

Use this instead of the construct `if (s.pop() == '}')`

Comment: So you do realize you have this pattern in more than one place ;) fix it in those places too. Understand I am not going to do your entire assignment either.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I updated the code.  How would I go about dealing with the bottom part of the Matcher class?

Comment: it will still throw, but you can also have it just return 0 if `s.isEmpty()`

Comment: For some reason it works each time but when I send in like {()()[(a==b)]}} it should say that there are too many closed symbols but it sends empty error up at the top.  for(int i =0; i<str.length(); i++){
   char c=str.charAt(i);
   if(c=='{' || c=='[' || c=='('){
    s.push(c);
   }else if (c=='}'){
    Character temp=s.pop();
    if(temp!='{'){
     s.push(temp);
     return MatchRtnCode.UNEXPECTED_SYMBOL;
    }

Comment: dude I updated the code with an encapsulated way. I told you if you wanted to add a check for empty you can/should depending on how you expected to use the peek() method